# Topic involving software primarily used for programming is closed as off-topic. Why is reopening it rejected?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The question [Removing projects in Sublime Text 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744365/removing-projects-in-sublime-text-2-and-3) is currently closed as being off-topic for this reason:

- "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. You may be able to get help on Super User."

How is the question off-topic then? Sublime Text is definitely software primarily used for programming/editing code.

I flagged the question for moderator attention and stated that it should be reopened, but the flag was declined. Can someone clarify things and tell me why this question should not be reopened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the question, I believe you are right: it should be reopened. There are also several comments to that effect.

But if you want something reopened, flagging is not the appropriate action. As is occasionally stated, moderators function here as “human exception handlers”, and generally they should only be flagged when the action cannot be performed by other users. While you may not be able to cast reopen votes, others can, and moderators generally do not like to function as a proxy for those without privileges to do such actions.

So what can you do? If you can find a relevant room in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), you may want to send a message asking if it really should have been closed. If you’re lucky, some other users with reopen-vote-casting privileges will agree with you and cast a reopen vote. You could also create a question on Meta like you did here, which also draws attention from users with the ability to cast reopen votes. [Productively] editing a closed question will bump it into the reopen review queue; adding a comment (as you did) along with that would provide reason for people in the queue to submit a reopen vote if it is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Alright, I understand now that flagging it for moderator attention was not the right choice. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I thought only questions that were "put on hold" would be sent to the review queue by editing them, has that changed?

Comment: I want to add that we have the [**SO Close vote reviewers room**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) were we handle the close vote queue but also help in re-opening questions. The regulars in that room have the privilege to cast re-open votes as well...

Comment: @Qantas: You’re probably right; I guess I didn’t take that into account. Still, a constructive change would bump it onto the home page for a little while, which might attract some attention (though not necessarily from reopeners).